# How To Center Lists in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to start with a simple website and I want to know how I can align my navigation bar. My navigation bar is in the form of a list. I'm not sure why the list's position seems a bit out of place when implementing it. So far, I've double-checked for closed tags and any modifications in styling my list. I expected the output of the page to have an even gap at its borders, but the list is instead crooked by a few pixels.

```css
#mainnav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#mainnav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

#mainnav ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
  /* spacing in-between the boxes */
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  /* spacing inside the boxes */
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="mainnav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index" class="nav-home">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="about-me.html" class="nav-about-me">ABOUT ME</a></li>
      <li><a href="vpnhole.html" class="nav-vpnhole">VPNHOLE</a></li>
      <li><a href="projects.html" class="nav-projects">PROJECTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="misc.html" class="nav-misc">MISC.</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Edit: Attached is a short video showing the change in the bar's position with and without setting padding to zero (from marked answer). It is somewhat difficult for me to visually represent the position of the navigation bar (the gray background probably gets pushed off the screen when aligning). https://youtu.be/J5XwdJn1pDA

Comment: There is an extra closing `div` before `nav`.

Comment: `I expected the output of the navigation links to be aligned where one link is aligned to the picture` what picture?

Comment: Add picture code also

Comment: Can you please send your expected output picture so we can understand clearly.

Comment: Already navigation elements are in the centre can you please explain clearly what you want.

Comment: There's an extra div because it ended a division to align a picture to the center (not here).

Comment: Show more code please. Noone can help you without understanding the problem.

Comment: @UbuntuResearcher What is your expected output?

Comment: Navigation links aligning to center.

Comment: @Arshiya Khanam I have a picture to include for the code output.

Comment: For future visitors: Please avoid using `float` for your `li`. This may cause unintended issues later on. Set them as `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` with the `text-align: center` on the `ul` and not the `#mainnav`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood the task - it should help

```
ul{
    padding: 0;
}
```